# VARIABLES GITLAB CI/CD kubectl

Tags: gitlab-ci, kubectl, gitlab-ci-runner

i have this gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - lang
  - db

variables:
  repo: "cidcd-runner"
  dir: "/var/www/html/moodle/report/"
  KUBE: $(kubectl get ns | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | grep -vE 'NAME|default|kube-node-lease|kube-public|kube-system')

job-lang:
  stage: lang
  script:
    - for i in $(kubectl get ns | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | grep -vE 'NAME|default|kube-node-lease|kube-public|kube-system'); do
        if [ -z $(kubectl exec cron-$i-0 -n $i -- ls -l $dir | grep $repo | awk -F " " '{print ($NF)}') ]; then
          echo NO esta en $i;
        else 
          echo esta en $i;
        fi;
      done
  tags:
    - onlytest
```

i want use varibakle KUBE in for, but when i exceute pipiline i have this error

```
$ for i in $kube; do if [ -z $(kubectl exec cron-$i-0 -n $i -- ls -l $dir | grep $repo | awk -F " " '{print ($NF)}') ]; then echo NO esta en $i; else echo esta en $i; fi; done
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "`kubectl" not found
NO esta en `kubectl
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "get" not found
NO esta en get
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "ns" not found
NO esta en ns
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "|" not found
```

How i can use variable inside for

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error, I wonder if the extra pipes with the `awk` and `$1` messes things, can you try replacing your command that gets the namespace names with the following instead:

`kubectl get ns -o custom-columns=:metadata.name --no-headers --field-selector metadata.name!=NAME,metadata.name!=default,metadata.name!=kube-system,metadata.name!=kube-public,metadata.name!=kube-node-lease`

This is a one-liner that doesn't make use of pipes.

EDIT: does it work properly when you don't use the KUBE env var?